# iPhone - Handling NSError into a scope

Tags: iphone, error-handling, dns, nserror

I'm trying to handle errors, and I find it very hard to know what kind of errors can be returned to me.
For example, I have this delegate method called from a map view manipulation :

```
- (void) reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

How may I know what kind of errors can be sent to me through this method ?
I don't want to have to handle the whole error catalog... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MKReverseGeocoder.h says:

```
// There are at least two types of errors:
//   - Errors sent up from the underlying connection (temporary condition)
//   - Result not found errors (permanent condition).  The result not found errors
//     will have the domain MKErrorDomain and the code MKErrorPlacemarkNotFound
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

Guess you should read docs and headers before asking.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't find what you are pointing into the doc : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoderDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MKReverseGeocoderDelegate I shouldn't have to read the headers to find what I'm supposed to handle. Isn't there a doc for that ? How may I do if a method header does not give me those tips ? And these lines does not tell exactly what errors will be given. One must understand that MKErrorCode is linked with MKErrorDomain. Not trivial.